# How can I identify a controller method / SQL query by the Azure Portal Query ID?

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, azureportal

In Azure Portal you can view your SQL database performance by clicking "Query Performance Insight" on the navigation bar on the left.

Here you can see some details on your top 5 queries.

[Azure Portal Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ll349.png)

The queries are given an ID - and you can drill into them to see the raw SQL commands that execute.
But of course the controller method written in c# looks vastly different and simplified compared to this.

What I'm currently doing is Console.WriteLine(someQuery) and comparing the terminal output in VS code to the raw SQL in VS code.

While this works it is tedious and cumbersome. Is there any way in Azure Portal to see what line of code this SQL command is being executed from, or line up the Query ID to the Method it is used in?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, there isn't a way in Azure Portal to see what line of code this SQL command is being executed from and line up the Query ID to the Method it is used in.

We can't see these messages or logs in Portal.